# Is it possible to use "would+perfect infinitive" after "if" in the future time contexts?

Tags: tense

1. "Asked if I would have chosen to support the attorney in court in May 2022, I said I could support him under special circumstances only."
2. "If I would have chosen to support the attorney in court in May 2022, I could support him under special circumstances only."

How can these patterns be interpreted in simpler grammatical constructions to preserve the tints of meaning conveyed by using "would"?

What time can "my having chosen" be referred to as compared to the moment of "asking (no.1)/my uttering (no.2)"?

Comment: _Would have chosen_ implies a possibility that existed in the past, not the future. "I would have voted for President Roosevelt if I had been alive then." (NB Months take a capital letter in English.)

Comment: Thanks for pointing to one particular set of words. For other concerns about "is it grammatical," can you edit the question to point to other specific concerns? For instance, I'm not sure whether you're thinking of the sentence structure and its phrases, of the verb tenses, or of issues about reported speech.

Comment: Also, you ask about "tints of meaning," but the two sentences say entirely different things. One talks about "special circumstances," the other about "familiarizing with the issues." One reports earlier speech, the other doesn't. Maybe edit to make them as parallel as possible except for whatever difference you want to focus on.

Comment: @Andy Bonner I have edited the question.

Comment: My concern is about using "will" in its modal meaning of volition and its milder form "would". I.e. I imply the following line of transformation: "If I choose to support the attorney in court in May 2022, I can support him..."-"If I have chosen to support the attorney in court in May 2022, I can support him..."-"If I will (stong volition in the near future) have chosen to support the attorney in court in May 2022, I can support him..."-"If I would (milder volition, assumption/presumption in the near future) have chosen to support the attorney in court in May 2022, I can support him...".

Comment: There is no future here at all.  Your usages above are a bit mixed up: If I choose to, I can. If I chose to, I would. If I had chosen to, I would have. But here you need whether.

Answer (score 0):

"Asked if I would have chosen to support the attorney in court in May 2022, I said I could support him under special circumstances only."= Indirect speech

There is nothing "simpler" that preserves the meaning of "would have chosen".

**DIRECT SPEECH**

- "**Would you have chosen** to support the attorney in court in May 2022?", the reporter asked. = direct speech

**INDIRECT SPEECH**

"Asked **whether** I would have chosen to support the attorney in court in May 2022, I said I could support him under special circumstances only."

With **whether**, there is an **implied if clause**.

Asked whether I would have chosen to support the attorney in court in May 2022, [if x conditions had been fulfilled], I said I could support him under special circumstances only.

*Asked if I would have chosen* is not grammatical here.

Comment: It means that x conditions were not fulfilled and I didn't choose to support the attorney? Or it had been still unclear by the moment of asking whether x conditions were fulfilled?

Comment: Not at all. I am saying that when you use: "I would have chosen", there is an if clause implied. In your example, I have no idea what it is. This condition does not actually have to be spelled out to be "hovering in the background". It could be as obvious as: I would have chosen to support, if they had asked me. "Asked whether I would have chosen to go, I said no." You really have to try and feel this if clause.

Comment: Is it right to say: "Asked whether I would have chosen to go if they had invited me, I said I could visit them"?

Comment: Yes, that's fine.

Comment: One more variant, if you please: The reporter asked: "Will you have chosen to support the attorney in court in May 2022 in case you are provided with necessary files?" I said: "I can support him only when I am in the town." Does this indirect speech correctly conveys the meaning of this text: "Asked if I would have chosen to support the attorney in court in May 2022 in case I be provided with necessary files, I said I could support him only when I was in the town"?

Comment: @Eugene No, that is not right. Person 1: Have you chosen to support the attorney? Person 2: No, I haven't. Person 2: Will you have chosen to support the attorney **by next week**? For example. Again, your use of "if" is not great. "Asked **whether** is better. Otherwise, it's OK.

Comment: So, I should have written: "Asked whether I would have chosen to support the attorney in court by next week in case I be provided with necessary files, I said I could support him"?

Comment: Asked whether I would have chosen to support the attorney in court  next week [in case I was provided with necessary files] I said I could support him. But you don't have to actually state what is in [...], as I already said.

Comment: Thank you a load of lots! And sorry for my having taken up your time. (Is it possible to use, if I want to sound old-fashioned, the Present Subjunctive after "in case", "so that"? I.e. "in case/so that  I/he/she/they be/do/arrive..."?)

Comment: @Eugene You are overstepping the rules here. Too much text. But no, in case does not "take subjunctive".